# Jersey consumes json, throw No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

### when I use Jersey consumes json, I got the following exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2173)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2106)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
```

### Here is my web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

### Here is my jersey version

```
com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.8
com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.8
com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.8
```

### Here is my java code

```
@POST
@Path("/save-coming-call-info")
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ComingCallInfo saveComingCallInfo(ComingCallInfo comingCallInfo) {
    comingCallInfo.setComingPhoneNo("234");
    return comingCallInfo;
}
```

### POJO

```
public class ComingCallInfo {
    private String phoneRecordFileId;
    private String comingPhoneNo;
    private String suiluData;
    //...get and set
}
```

### Here is jquery post

```
var url="";
var comingCallInfo = new Object();
comingCallInfo.comingPhoneNo = comingPhoneNo;
comingCallInfo.suiluData = suiluData
comingCallInfo.phoneRecordFileId = phoneRecordFileId;
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify(comingCallInfo),
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data, status, xhr) {

    },
    error : function(data, status, xhr){

    }
});
```

### could anyone can tell me why the exception throw, and what should I change.